# Panda variance row wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi everyone I am a beginner in python. I have a dataset that looks like the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [1,2,3], "b" : [[1,2],[2,3,4],[5]]})
   a          b
0  1     [1, 2]
1  2  [2, 3, 4]
2  3        [5]
```

and I wanted to calculate the variance of every row.  I tried to use

> df.var(axis=1)

But it always returns NAN NAN. I have no NA/null values in my dataset. Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: That's because you have lists/objects in your cells instead of numbers.

Comment: I thought that Pands would Automatically handle it. Should I try to split them ? or there's a specific function/method in pandas solves this issue Automatically?

Comment: @QuangHoang is right. Use ```.apply()``` function. You can see a couple of them in my answering history. Alternatively, you can provide me with the data, to give you your desired code

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you are looking for:

```
df['b'].apply(np.var)
```

output:

```
0    0.250000
1    0.666667
2    0.000000
```